# How can I control float input in c?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define MAX 4

int main(){
    int i;
    float x1, y1, x2, y2;
    float sumx1 = 0;
    float sumy1 = 0;
    float sumx2 = 0;
    float sumy2 = 0;
    int drm = MAX/2;

    printf("please enter first class(include 4 point)\n");
    
    for(i = 0; i < MAX/2; i++){
        printf("%d. line---->", i);
        scanf("%f  %f", &x1, &y1); 
        sumx1 += x1;
        sumy1 += y1;

        if(i == drm - 1){
            printf("%d. line---->end of class-1-\n", i + 1);
        }
    }
        
    for(i = (MAX/2) + 1; i <= MAX; i++){
        printf("%d. line---->", i);
        scanf("%f  %f", &x2, &y2);
        sumx2 += x2;
        sumy2 += y2;

        if(i == MAX){
            printf("%d. line---->end of class-2-\n", i + 1);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I get `x` and `y` coordinates from the user in this code. I want the `x` and `y*` values to `float`, and I want to check that. If the values entered are not `float` numbers, I want to finish the program. I can't use array or different library when I do this.

How can I control float number?

```
if (scanf("%f %f",x,y) == 0)
```

I remember using a structure in the style, but unfortunately I did not find the result.

Comment: Something like `if (scanf("%f %f", &x1, &y1) != 2) {` `fprintf(stderr, "Bad input\n");` `exit(1);` `}` would print an error and exit if the `scanf` call failed to read 2 `float` values.

Comment: Like most functions, it's a good idea to read the documentation to see what the return value indicates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scanf` returns the number of inputs successfully converted and assigned, so as a first step you need to check the return value:

```
if ( scanf( "%f %f", &x1, &y1 ) != 2 )
{
  // handle bad input
}
else
{
  // process x1 and y1
}
```

If you enter something like `"1.0 2.0"`, `scanf` will successfully convert both values and assign them to `x1` and `y1` and return `2`.  If you enter something like `"1.0 abc"`, `scanf` will convert and assign `1.0` to `x1`, stop reading as soon as it sees `"abc"` (and not update `y1`), and return 1.  And if you enter `"abcdef"`, nothing gets assigned to either `x1` or `y1` and `scanf` returns `0`.

If you enter something like `"1.0 2abc"`, `scanf` will read and convert the `"1.0"` and set `x1` to `1.0` as expected.  It will also read and convert the `"2"` from `"2abc"` and set `y1` to `2.0`, and `scanf` will return `2`.  This is not a good situation - you would probably want to reject that `"2abc"` altogether, but `scanf` with `%f` by itself can't do that.

The problem you have to deal with now is that those characters that weren't converted are still in the input stream - until you remove them with some other input operation, they will prevent any further floating-point inputs from being recognized.  So as part of handling bad input, you need to clear out the input stream.  We'll rewrite our check as follows:

```
/**
 * Repeat input operation until we get two good inputs:
 */
while ( scanf( "%f %f", &x1, &y1 ) != 2 )
{
  /**
   * First make sure there isn't a problem with the input stream itself;
   * if there is, exit the program at this point.
   */
  if ( feof( stdin ) || ferror( stdin ) )
  {
    fprintf( stderr, "Error or EOF on stdin, exiting...\n" );
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  /**
   * Bad input, read and discard everything up to the next newline
   */
  while ( getchar() != '\n' )
    ; // empty loop

  printf( "Bad input, try again: " );
}
// process x1 and y1
```

By itself, `scanf` really isn't a good tool for validating input, but this should get you going.  Just be aware that the solution above *won't* catch the `"1.0 2abc"` case, but I don't think you want to get into those weeds right now.